# webpack difference between import("path") and import "path"

Tags: webpack, import

What is the difference between

```
import( "file.js" );
```

and

```
import "file.js";
```

Both syntax are valid, but second case is sometime works improperly ib browser.

Answer (score 2):

This is all about "bundles" and "chunks".

If you think of modules as individual lego pieces, then a bundle is a lego set. It's all the pieces you need to construct a final model.

However, continuing the lego analogy for a moment, it's helpful in some larger, more complex builds to break the set into smaller parts that can be assembled individually and then combined at the end. In fact, for some lego sets, parts of the set might even be optional. For example, I bought a set featuring a space shuttle and a transport truck. They were individual builds that perfectly complemented one another and could be combined at the end to complete the model, but if all you really wanted was the shuttle then the truck need not even be constructed.

Webpack, similarly, allows you to break up a "bundle" into "chunks" that can be dynamically loaded, or not, as needed. Once present these chunks form a single, cohesive bundle that works seamlessly, but you have the option to simply not load parts of the bundle that aren't needed, or to delay loading them until they are actually required.

`import "Foo"` creates a "hard" link between two modules, telling Webpack that the current module can't run without the Foo module.

`import("Foo")` creates a "soft" link between two modules, telling Webpack that the current module might need the other module, but it can be put in a separate chunk to be loaded later when needed. For example, you might only need `Foo` under a handful of unusual circumstances, and if you need that module then it's ok to wait for `Foo` to be available. At runtime, the chunk will be loaded when the `import()` function is called.

`import()` returns a promise that will resolve when the modules within the chunk are available. You will need to wait for the promise to resolve: `const Foo = await import("Foo");` or `import("Foo").then(function(Foo){ /* ... */ })`

In either case, the modules can all interact with one another seamlessly as a single bundle.

So, for clarity:

**Module A:**

```
import B from "B"

async function loadOptionalFeature() {
  const C = await import(
    /* webpackChunkName: "optional-chunk" */
    "C"
  );
  // ...
}
```

**Module B:**

```
import D from "D"
```

**Module C:**

```
import D from "D"
import E from "E"
```

[image]

`A` is my entry file. Webpack will construct a core chunk that includes `A`. Because `A` has a hard link to `B`, `B` will also be included in the core chunk. Because `B` has a hard link to `D`, `D` will also be included in the core chunk.

`A` has a "soft" link to `C`, so webpack *may* divide `C` into its own chunk (there are may configuration options available). `C` has a "hard" link to `D`, but `D` is already included in the core chunk so it's not included in the `optional-chunk`. `C` also has a "hard" link to `E` and, since `E` is not included in the core chunk, it's included in the `optional-chunk`.